Ballistic Coefficients in a Zero G and Perfect Vacuum
I originally asked if a weapon system like the .17HMR would be more effective in Zero-G and Vacuum. Allow me to reword it: If I understand how space should work, then is a chemically propelled weapon the best option, or would a weapon like a crossbow or longbow be better? For options like air rifles, you run the risk of decompression before firing the projectile. Would a system that fires based solely off of kinetic energy work better? (My thanks to TheDemonLord for helping me with my first question.)

Cartridges carry their own oxidizer, if that's what you mean, and there's no ballistic coefficient in space because there's no atmosphere. The gun will just need to have a cold-gas thruster which fires in the opposite direction during each firing if you don't want recoil.

A weapon system to shoot at what type of target (armour, vulnerabilities) at what range in what conditions (eg relative movement) with what cost/production restrictions?  (For completeness, should also specify who/what will be employing the weapon, but the examples suggest it will be a human or something similar.)  In some scenarios throwing a rock or spanner will hit the optimal utility/price combination, in others a gyro-stabilised laser will be the only useful option.

It sounds like you are asking several unrelated questions.  Do you want to know if chemical projectiles are still effective in space, do you want to know if compressed air or crossbows are viable alternatives to guns, or are you asking about how Zero G and Perfect Vacuum would impact the relative effectiveness of small fast bullets vs large slow arrows?

I agree, the question needs narrowing to a single issue. We like to be lenient on new users but voting to put on hold until the question can be edited to be more focused.

I have a addition to make. Firing a weapon near a body of gravity.. can have all sorts of weird effects. Depending on the trajectory, the bullet may circle around a planet similar to the ISS and come around, up and behind. You can also have projectiles, who intercept one another and detonate in spectacular flashes of energy. All you need is perfect ballistic information- aka computational power and sensors. You can also... fire pre-emptively. As in, your gun, is far far away (out of sight behind a planetary curve, outside of a solar system), aimed ahead of time at a trajectory. You are armed-

Are we asking about personal weapons, turretted weapons, or missiles? Is the target distance measured in meters, kilometers, or lightseconds? You're not allowed to ask for everything, so please [edit] your question identifying just one condition from each of the two categories. Thanks.

Yes, rather broad. The issue I see is that there is no meaningful difference if you're discussing propulsion methods. If you're talking the size and shape of projectile, then its effectiveness will vary based on the size of the shooter and the qualities of the target. Fore instance, I'll take a broadhead arrow over birdshot if you're trying to puncture a Whipple shield, but birdshot would be considerably more effective against a space suit.
